# Stored procedure in loop

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
for (int i = 0; i < purchaseListView.Items.Count; i++)
Connection con = new Connection();
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                 SqlCommand cmdFifo = new SqlCommand();
                 con.OpenConnection();
                 cmd.Connection = con.DataBaseConnection;
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 cmd.CommandText = "insertDetail";
                 cmdFifo.Connection = con.DataBaseConnection;
                 cmdFifo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 cmdFifo.CommandText = "insertInToMain";
```

This is my code and I want to know if the loop affects performance of my software and if this is the right way to call stored procedure in loop.

I have stored the procedure in a class and I want to call it from a form when the save button is clicked and insert 10 items in the database via same stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new connection object for every item which is highly inefficient.

Create one connection object and execute the stored procedure `n` times with the product details.  Alternatively create a stored procedure to accept 10 items and insert the data at that level.

Move this outside the loop (You can access `con` and `cmd` inside the loop without creating a new instance:

```
  Connection con = new Connection();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  con.OpenConnection();
  cmd.Connection = con.DataBaseConnection;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.CommandText = "insertDetail";
```

Inside your loop, you can add all the parameters to the `cmd` object.

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters["@Item"].Value = purchaseListView.Items[i];
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: isit efficient to do
    con.open()
    for (int i = 0;i < purchaseListView.Items.Count;i++)

                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                 SqlCommand cmdFifo = new SqlCommand();
                 con.OpenConnection();
                 cmd.Connection = con.DataBaseConnection;
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 cmd.CommandText = "insertDetail";
                 cmdFifo.Connection = con.DataBaseConnection;
                 cmdFifo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 cmdFifo.CommandText = "insertInToMain";

Comment: @user2174542 - not really.  The main inefficiency is that you are in a loop and creating a lot of redundant objects (i.e. using new SQLCommand() inside the loop).  You can reuse objects like I have shown you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are opening 10 connections, and it seems that you are not closing them, so you may run out of connections, but im guessing that's not the whole code, could you post the entire for ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your connection and stored procedure before the loop and only update command parameter values and exec within the loop.  Like this:

```
Connection con = new Connection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlCommand cmdFifo = new SqlCommand();
con.OpenConnection();
cmd.Connection = con.DataBaseConnection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "insertDetail";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.Int); 
cmdFifo.Connection = con.DataBaseConnection;
cmdFifo.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmdFifo.CommandText = "insertInToMain";
//now that your connections & commands are set up, you can reuse them within the loop
for (int i = 0; i < purchaseListView.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //ToDo:assign any SP parameter values
    cmd.Parameters["@Item"].Value = purchaseListView.Items[i]; 
    // ...

    //then exec within the loop
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmdFifo.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: i want to keep code for passing parameter in a class and and call stored procedure on click of save button.. i want to open connection only once and call stored procedure. can u please give me a demo code, please!

Comment: It is best if you assign SP parameter(s) and run the SP within the same class.  It makes the OO design more atomic.  It also helps avoid connection leaks as @jcarlos pointed out. (as long as you close & dispose in your class properly).

Comment: if connection and sqlcommand() aand following code are in some block of function in a class the how to can i call only <code>
'cmd.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.Int);
 cmd.Parameters["@Item"].Value = purchaseListView.Items[i];
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();'
</code>

Comment: See my edit.  I added the param before the loop.  Then, within the loop, I assign it and exec.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a table and insert the whole data into it by iterating through all the inputs ie., try to create a single stored procedure. 
Running a for loop multpile times is inefficient and also the database will generate the result set number of times which will affect your performance as well due to network overhead.